# Node/MongoDB Weekly DB maintenance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I wrote an MEAN application hosted on Heroku + MLab and am wondering how to run daily maintenance for the DB.

The data objects are all date related and I'd like to run a script somehow once every week to delete all entries with expired dates. Does Heroku have some code you can write some where that will do this data scrub on a set interval?

P.S. I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TTL (time to live) is the concept you're looking for and mongo has a buit in method for it !

if you use the native mongo driver without mongoose you will have to declare it when you declare your indexes like so

```
db.MYDB.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

here we create an index for the  (already) existing field createdAt and it expires in 3600 seconds

if you use mongoose and have a date field type at your document you can pass `expires`  as the second argument

`new Schema({ createdAt: { type: Date, expires: 3600 }});`

in this case the document has a field named createdAt with a date and it expires in 3600 seconds which is 1 hour

hope it helps !

Comment: Ho Lee Crap that is awesome. Thank!